# Google Analytics event tracking code being stripped out of links in Author box - WordPress site

Tags: plugins, google-analytics

I am using Yoast's Google Analytics plugin on my WordPress site. I have enabled Event Tracking for outbound links and have successfully manually added event tracking for some other internal links. It all works fine EXCEPT for in the 'Author Box'. Under each post I created an author box which pulls "the_author_description" from the user profile. This seems to strip out the GA event tracking code. I have an outbound link in there which should automatically be tracked by the plugin but the code is not there. If I try and manually add the code to any of the links in the user profile, they also get stripped out. 
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think its because the tracking code is stripped out but that it never made it to your 'Author Box.'

I'll try to look into the plugin later, but my guess is that the plugin will filter the page's content from hooks and filters.